# number filteration in jtable

Tags: java, swing

I have a `jtextfield` above each column header with which I am trying to filter on numbers like > numb, < num, !num, ==num, <=num, >=num.

For example if I enter >=100 in the `jtextfield` by splitting it should fetch me filtered results of numbers greater than or equal to 100.

I have used many `if` `else` conditions inside a button action listener method but after few if else the others are not working fine,but when run separately it's working. How to resolve this?

```
import javax.swing.RowFilter.ComparisonType;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TableFilter {

    public TableFilter() {

        Object[][] rows
                = {{100, "Aaa",10},
                {101, "Bbb",11},
                {102, "Ccc",5},
                {103, "Ddd",3},
                {104, "Eee",2},
                {105, "Fff",5},
                {106, "Ggg",11},
                {107, "Hhh",8} };


        String[] column = {"empno", "name","experience"};
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, column) {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
              Class returnValue;
              if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
                returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
              } else {
                returnValue = Object.class;
              }
              return returnValue;
            }
          };

          final JTable table = new JTable(model);
          final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
          table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        JTextField jtf1 = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField jtf2 = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField jtf3 = new JTextField(5);
       JButton b1 = new JButton ("ENTER");
        ///////////////////EQUAL      
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = jtf1.getText();

            if (text.length() == 0) {
            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
            }

            else if(text.startsWith("="))
            {
                String[] parts = text.split("=");
                String part1 = parts[1]; 
                sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(part1));}
            else if(text.startsWith("!"))
             {
                String[] parts = text.split("!");
                String part1 = parts[1]; 
                sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(part1)));
              }

            else if(text.startsWith(">"))
           {
            String[] parts = text.split(">");
            String part1 = parts[1];
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, Integer.parseInt(part1)));
           }
            else if(text.startsWith("<"))
               {
                //System.out.println("*****************");
                String[] parts = text.split("<");
                String part1 = parts[1];

                List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);                
                Number numb=Integer.parseInt(part1);

                filters.add(0,RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER,numb)));
                filters.add(0,RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.EQUAL,numb)));
                DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<>(dtm);
                table.setRowSorter(tr);
                RowFilter<Object, Object> rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
                tr.setRowFilter(rf); 
               }
             else if(text.startsWith(">="))
               {
                 System.out.println("*****************");
                 String[] p1=text.split(">");
                 String p2=p1[1];
                 String[] p3=p2.split("=");
                 String pf=p3[1];
                 Number numb=Integer.parseInt(pf);
                   // String s=text.substring(2);
                List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2); 

                filters.add(0,RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.EQUAL,numb));
                filters.add(0,RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER,numb));
                DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<>(dtm);
                table.setRowSorter(tr);
                RowFilter<Object, Object> rf = RowFilter.orFilter(filters);
                tr.setRowFilter(rf);
               }

            else if(text.startsWith("<="))
           {
             String[] p1=text.split("<");
             String p2=p1[1];
             String[] p3=p2.split("=");
             String pf=p3[1];
             //Number numb=Integer.parseInt(pf);
                //String sub=text.substring(2);

                sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, Integer.parseInt(pf))));
            }
            }
            }
        );
 JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        panel.add(jtf1);
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(350));
        panel.add(jtf2);
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(350));
        panel.add(jtf3);
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(150));
        panel.add(b1);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TableFilter();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try debugging line by line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will definitely resolve your problem.

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private List<String> operaters=Arrays.asList(new String []{">", "<", "!", "==", "<=", ">="});
    private String filterPattern="[0-9]|[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]";
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {           
        applyFilter(jtf1.getText(),0);

    }

    private void applyFilter(String text,int columnIndex) {
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            //sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        }else{


            String operator=text.toString().split(filterPattern)[0];
            if(operaters.contains(operator)){
                String value=text.split(operator).length>1?text.split(operator)[1]:"";
                sorter.setRowFilter(getRowFilter(operator,value,columnIndex));
            }

        }

    }

    private RowFilter<? super TableModel, ? super Integer> getRowFilter(
            String operator, String value,int columnIndex) {

        if (operator.equals("==")) {
            return RowFilter.regexFilter(value);
        } else if (operator.equals("!")) {

            return RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(value,columnIndex));
        }

        else if (operator.equals(">")) {

            return RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER,
                    Integer.parseInt(value),columnIndex);
        } else if (operator.equals("<")) {

            Number numb = Integer.parseInt(value);

            return RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, numb,columnIndex);
        } else if (operator.equals(">=")) {

            Number numb = Integer.parseInt(value);
            // String s=text.substring(2);
            List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>(
                    2);

            filters.add(0,
                    RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.EQUAL, numb,columnIndex));
            filters.add(0,
                    RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, numb,columnIndex));

            return RowFilter.orFilter(filters);
        }

        else if (operator.equals("<=")) {

            Number numb = Integer.parseInt(value);
            // String s=text.substring(2);
            List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>(
                    2);

            filters.add(0,
                    RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.EQUAL, numb,columnIndex));
            filters.add(0,
                    RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, numb,columnIndex));
            return RowFilter.orFilter(filters);
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
);
```